# Keyboard.GetState() only work first time, and Memory increase (not Disposing)

Tags: xna, c#, monogame, sharpdx

**EDIT UPDATE 3**
I been searching the web for a solution and found several people struggling with Memoryleak using MonoGame while trying to dispose objects.
It could be the case that MonoGame should be started and then closed as a own process, not from another program which are my case.
When I click on the button, a new thread is created and the MonoGame application is started:

```
 viThread = new Thread(startDemo);
 viThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
 viThread.Start();


 private void startDemo()
 {
        using (Demo d = new Demo())
            d.Run();
 }
```

The "Demo" is closed by a Game.Exit command and i have also tried with Disposed(true) without any success. Next time I launch the MonoGame is Keyboard.GetsState() always empty and the memory is incresed. I made a loop where I started and closed the application 100times and it are eating my memory. I have seen lots of discussion about SharpDX not working correcly with dispsing resources. So here I am, stuck. Just want to point out that this worked fine for XNA but not now when changed to MonoGame. And again, thanks for all comments I got so far.

I have uploaded a project where you can see the issue by yourself. The second time dosn't the keyboard input work but mouseinput does and the memory is increasing for each time:

[Donwload sln project](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=05943256822998486463&t=0594325682299848646345587)

**EDIT UPDATE 4**

It is SharpDX which increase the memory, I perform following line before i exit:

```
SharpDX.Diagnostics.ObjectTracker.ReportActiveObjects().Length
```

And its increasing all the time. So I guess it isnt released.
Someone know how to do that?

Comment: If you just call `d.Run()` without instanciating a new `Game`, does it work?

Comment: Second time I come to d.Run() the object d is null so I have to make a new instance of it.

Comment: What do you mean with main() method?
If you wounder of how the Game is started you can see it as a WinForms where I click on a button and the code:
Game d = new Game();
d.Run()

Comment: See my comment below, I think its something about game not disposed but with the "using" statement I still get the same error

Comment: Seems like a very odd thing to do (restarting the game after it exits). Can you explain why you need to do this?

Comment: I downloaded and ran your project and had absolutely no problems with it, except from when I try to open 2 games at the same time, which shouldn't be allowed anyway. When I open 2 games in a row, only the second one registers my keyboard input. When I close the 2nd one, then the 1st one works. You should be hiding the winform after the game starts. On a sidenote, you should built the GUI with graphics, not winforms in the first place.

Comment: We are using a Winform/WPF application where the "game" is just a video demostration, not an actually game, which is the reason. Otherwise I totaly agree on building everything inside the game.
I will see if changing the Winforms (hide/show) will help, however the application is still growing in memory so items arn't disposed as they should be.

Comment: @user2605871 Did you try disposing *after* exiting? It sounds like there's an issue with the first instance keeping hold of the inputs, so your best bet would be to figure out how to properly dispose of the resources in MonoGame.

Comment: Richard, I think you are right. See my latest update. However, I cant get the resources to dispose. The memory is still increasing even when i use this.Dispose(). I think somwhere I have to point at SharpDX resources explicit but not sure if or how.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to dispose your game object.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    using (Game1 game = new Game1())
        game.Run();
    using (Game1 game = new Game1())
        game.Run();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, same problem.
However, before when I was using XNA, we did:
this.Dispose; 
this.Exit();

I had to remove the "this.Dispose", since it crashed on "this.Exit" now, so it could be something with that.

Comment: @user2605871 Did you try with this `main()` method I showed you. Try this first see if it works, cause for me it does. I am using `this.Exit();` to end my game. There could be something else you are doing wrong in other parts of your code that you are not showing.

Comment: It works actually when I do it like you showed, two times in a row. So there must be something that happens in between?

Comment: The problem is that when i click on a button, the game starts and works fine. Then i close the game.
Then from the meny I would like to start it again without restart the entire application and now it dosnt react on keyboard. Its strange since it reacts on mouse/touch.

Comment: So put this code in your OnButtonClick: `using (Game1 game = new Game1()) game.Run();` ?

Comment: I have done that, dosn't work.
                using (Cloud_Demo d = new Cloud_Demo())
                {
                    d.Run();
                }
                using (Cloud_Demo d = new Cloud_Demo())
                {
                    d.Run();
                }
Doing like that does it react on keys the second time the game start as well as first. But if I have the application running and press the game-start button again it dosnt. Feels like I have to dispose something, like keyboard is locked to that process.

Comment: @user2605871 Are you trying to run 2 games at the same time ? Or one after another with a winforms menu in between to start the game ? If you are trying to do the latter, the problem must be in how you close and re-open the winform.

Comment: I'm trying the latter.
Thanks for the help, I will continue tomorrow and let you know :)

Comment: I agreee, if we get a solution on this I will do a summery so people will find the answer. Please see the edit of my post. Greetings